# Proving that Every preference relation can be represented by utility function

Tags: mathematical-economics, preferences

Im looking the prove the following:

every preference relation ⪰ over finite/countable set X can be represented as a utility function u such that `x1 ⪰ x2 <=> u(x1) ≥ u(x2)`

At the first direction: `x1 ⪰ x2 => u(x1) ≥ u(x2)`, i just built a utility function `u` that is defined to be:
`u(xi) = |set of all xj such that xi ⪰ xj |`

the function is well defined since set X is countable, and therefore there is a finite number of options (xj) that are less than xi.

Im struggling with proving the other direction...
And so i hope that you can help me with that :)

Comment: Hi! What exactly do you mean by "*the other direction*"? Seems like you have to prove that a $u$ representing $\succeq$ exists. You constructed a function $u$. Does it represent $\succeq$ or not?

Comment: Well Im pretty much confused because i searched a lot on the web and yet everything I found is a prove to what you just wrote. Im trying to figure out if its the same as what Im trying to prove. Also, by "the other direction" - i mean to prove that from a function "u" i can create a preference relation i guess? im not quite certain, as im very confused by what is meant to be proven here...

Comment: The set in your definition of the utility function need not be finite, it can be countably infinite.

Comment: I didnt quite understand, if the set would be countably infinite, then the function might never return a value

Comment: @StrugglingResearcher Exactly, or a value of $\infty$, which is not a real number. The usual trick is to use a weighted sum like $u(x_i)=\sum_{j:x_j\preceq x_i} 1/2^i$.

Comment: I was told to prove it for a finite set, I guess it makes it a bit easier.   so is the first part of my prove is currect? and how should the second part be handled?